# Executing a suspend function in Kotlin only after another suspend function has completed?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

The app I'm developing functions like this

- upon first launch of the app, an onboarding screen is shown and its OnboardingViewModel is called
- there are 3 things which need to be done IN ORDER:

  1. check a `preferencesRepository` whether the onboarding has been completed;
  2. if the onboarding has not been completed, 2 suspend functions need to be executed in order:

     a) fetch remote data

     b) assign dates to all elements in the Room DB

How do I make sure that the things happen in order? My current implementation results in the second function being run twice, which produces wrong dates (there must be an element with the current date).

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class OnboardingViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val preferencesRepository: PreferencesRepository,
    private val repository: ItemRepository,
    private val unsplashRepository: UnsplashRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _tag = "OnboardingVM"
    private val today = LocalDate.now()

    private val _showOnboardingScreen = MutableStateFlow(true)
    val showOnboardingScreen = _showOnboardingScreen.asStateFlow()

    private var _itemsWithoutDate = mutableStateOf<List<Item>>(listOf())
    private var _itemsWithoutImage = mutableStateOf<List<Item>>(listOf())

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            checkStatus()
            if (_showOnboarding.value) {
                loadRemoteItems()
                assignDates()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun checkStatus() {
        _showOnboardingScreen.value =
preferencesRepository.readBool(Settings.SHOW_ONBOARDING_SCREEN) ?: true
        Log.d(_tag, "Show onboarding: ${showOnboardingScreen.value}")
    }

    private suspend fun loadRemoteItems() {

        Log.d(_tag, "Begin loading remote items")
        val remoteHash = try {
            repository.getHash()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("Ktor", "Error getting remote hash: $e")
            ""
        }
        Log.d(_tag, "Remote hash: [$remoteHash]")

        val localHash =
preferencesRepository.readString(Settings.LOCAL_HASH_STRING)
        Log.d(_tag, "Local hash: [$localHash]")

        if (remoteHash != "" && remoteHash != localHash) {
            Log.d(_tag, "Loading remote items")

            val remoteItems = try {
                repository.getAllRemote()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emptyList()
            }

            if (remoteItems.isNotEmpty()) {
                repository.insertAllRemote(remoteItems)
                preferencesRepository.setString(
                  Settings.LOCAL_HASH_STRING, 
                  remoteHash
                )
                preferencesRepository.setDate(
                    Settings.LAST_UPDATE_CHECK_DATE,
                    today.toEpochDay()
                )

                Log.d(_tag, "Loaded [${remoteItems.size}] remote items.")
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun assignDates() {
        _itemsWithoutDate.value = repository.getItemsWithoutDate()
        Log.d(_tag, "Items without date before: ${_itemsWithoutDate.value.size}")
        if (_itemsWithoutDate.value.isNotEmpty()) {
            repository.updateItemDate(_itemsWithoutDate.value.shuffled())
        }
        _itemsWithoutDate.value = repository.getItemsWithoutDate()
        Log.d(_tag, "Items without date after: ${_itemsWithoutDate.value.size}")
    }
}
```

**ItemRepository & DAO**

```kotlin
// Repository
suspend fun getItemsWithoutDate(): List<Item> {
    return dao.getItemsWithoutDate()
}

suspend fun updateItemDate(items: List<Item>) {
    val startDate = dao.getMaxDate()?.plusDays(1) ?: LocalDate.now()
    Log.d("DailyItemVM", "Repo. Updating items' dates. Start date: $startDate")
    var newDate: LocalDate

    for ((increment, item) in items.withIndex()) {
        newDate = LocalDate.from(startDate).plusDays(increment.toLong())
        dao.updateDate(item.id, newDate)
        Log.d("DailyItemVM", "Repo. Updated date of item: ${item.id} to $newDate")
    }
}

// DAO
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM item WHERE NULLIF(date, '') IS NULL")
suspend fun getItemsWithoutDate(): List<Item>

@Query("UPDATE item SET date = :date WHERE id = :id")
suspend fun updateDate(id: Int, date: LocalDate)
```

As you can see from the **LogCat** output below, the items' dates are updated twice (look where it says `Repo. Updating items' dates. Start date:`).

```
OnboardingVM    D  Begin loading remote items
OnboardingVM    D  Show onboarding: true
OnboardingVM    D  Show onboarding: true
OnboardingVM    D  Begin loading remote items
OnboardingVM    D  Remote hash: [c0a7239382390c64f4416dc11d3c6a4a6fa84c7c3e5e57073b712dcd0fa32153]
OnboardingVM    D  Local hash: [null]
OnboardingVM    D  Loading remote items
OnboardingVM    D  Loaded [204] remote items.
OnboardingVM    D  Items without date before: 208
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updating items' dates. Start date: 2023-08-16
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 239 to 2023-08-16
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 201 to 2023-08-17
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 323 to 2023-08-18
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 208 to 2023-08-19
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 298 to 2023-08-20
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 264 to 2023-08-21
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 380 to 2023-08-22
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 341 to 2023-08-23
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 332 to 2023-08-24
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 190 to 2023-08-25
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 350 to 2023-08-26
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 224 to 2023-08-27
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 238 to 2023-08-28
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 1 to 2023-08-29
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 2 to 2023-08-30
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 319 to 2023-08-31
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 277 to 2023-09-01
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 235 to 2023-09-02
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 295 to 2023-09-03
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 334 to 2023-09-04
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 366 to 2023-09-05
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 214 to 2023-09-06
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 326 to 2023-09-07
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 206 to 2023-09-08
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 260 to 2023-09-09
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 301 to 2023-09-10
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 371 to 2023-09-11
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 276 to 2023-09-12
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 196 to 2023-09-13
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 302 to 2023-09-14
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 327 to 2023-09-15
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 234 to 2023-09-16
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 229 to 2023-09-17
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 244 to 2023-09-18
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 219 to 2023-09-19
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 369 to 2023-09-20
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 386 to 2023-09-21
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 338 to 2023-09-22
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 231 to 2023-09-23
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 4 to 2023-09-24
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 355 to 2023-09-25
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 303 to 2023-09-26
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 192 to 2023-09-27
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 363 to 2023-09-28
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 227 to 2023-09-29
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 300 to 2023-09-30
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 313 to 2023-10-01
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 250 to 2023-10-02
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 268 to 2023-10-03
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 335 to 2023-10-04
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 328 to 2023-10-05
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 342 to 2023-10-06
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 333 to 2023-10-07
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 349 to 2023-10-08
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 7 to 2023-10-09
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 289 to 2023-10-10
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 378 to 2023-10-11
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 312 to 2023-10-12
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 296 to 2023-10-13
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 358 to 2023-10-14
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 316 to 2023-10-15
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 242 to 2023-10-16
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 286 to 2023-10-17
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 314 to 2023-10-18
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 216 to 2023-10-19
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 240 to 2023-10-20
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 339 to 2023-10-21
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 232 to 2023-10-22
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 282 to 2023-10-23
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 361 to 2023-10-24
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 189 to 2023-10-25
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 5 to 2023-10-26
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 353 to 2023-10-27
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 379 to 2023-10-28
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 259 to 2023-10-29
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 223 to 2023-10-30
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 389 to 2023-10-31
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 195 to 2023-11-01
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 308 to 2023-11-02
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 274 to 2023-11-03
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 291 to 2023-11-04
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 329 to 2023-11-05
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 262 to 2023-11-06
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 247 to 2023-11-07
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 360 to 2023-11-08
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 255 to 2023-11-09
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 315 to 2023-11-10
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 256 to 2023-11-11
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 233 to 2023-11-12
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 228 to 2023-11-13
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 273 to 2023-11-14
OnboardingVM    D  Remote hash: [c0a7239382390c64f4416dc11d3c6a4a6fa84c7c3e5e57073b712dcd0fa32153]
OnboardingVM    D  Local hash: [c0a7239382390c64f4416dc11d3c6a4a6fa84c7c3e5e57073b712dcd0fa32153]
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 270 to 2023-11-15
OnboardingVM    D  Items without date before: 116
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 352 to 2023-11-16
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updating items' dates. Start date: 2023-11-17
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 343 to 2023-11-17
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 251 to 2023-11-17
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 330 to 2023-11-18
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 261 to 2023-11-18
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 311 to 2023-11-19
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 373 to 2023-11-19
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 383 to 2023-11-20
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 215 to 2023-11-20
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 225 to 2023-11-21
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 336 to 2023-11-21
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 305 to 2023-11-22
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 241 to 2023-11-22
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 388 to 2023-11-23
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 265 to 2023-11-23
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 287 to 2023-11-24
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 347 to 2023-11-24
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 375 to 2023-11-25
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 306 to 2023-11-25
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 248 to 2023-11-26
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 376 to 2023-11-26
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 204 to 2023-11-27
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 287 to 2023-11-27
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 290 to 2023-11-28
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 275 to 2023-11-28
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 336 to 2023-11-29
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 374 to 2023-11-29
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 324 to 2023-11-30
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 200 to 2023-11-30
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 263 to 2023-12-01
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 279 to 2023-12-01
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 385 to 2023-12-02
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 212 to 2023-12-02
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 241 to 2023-12-03
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 365 to 2023-12-03
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 293 to 2023-12-04
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 236 to 2023-12-04
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 384 to 2023-12-05
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 237 to 2023-12-05
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 285 to 2023-12-06
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 209 to 2023-12-06
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 354 to 2023-12-07
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 252 to 2023-12-07
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 217 to 2023-12-08
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 321 to 2023-12-08
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 197 to 2023-12-09
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 320 to 2023-12-09
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 198 to 2023-12-10
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 225 to 2023-12-10
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 266 to 2023-12-11
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 211 to 2023-12-11
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 318 to 2023-12-12
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 243 to 2023-12-12
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 209 to 2023-12-13
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 281 to 2023-12-13
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 211 to 2023-12-14
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 254 to 2023-12-14
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 376 to 2023-12-15
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 359 to 2023-12-15
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 257 to 2023-12-16
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 348 to 2023-12-16
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 193 to 2023-12-17
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 292 to 2023-12-17
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 249 to 2023-12-18
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 218 to 2023-12-18
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 218 to 2023-12-19
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 330 to 2023-12-19
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 230 to 2023-12-20
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 346 to 2023-12-20
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 320 to 2023-12-21
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 340 to 2023-12-21
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 261 to 2023-12-22
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 193 to 2023-12-22
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 306 to 2023-12-23
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 388 to 2023-12-23
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 321 to 2023-12-24
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 246 to 2023-12-24
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 288 to 2023-12-25
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 294 to 2023-12-25
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 322 to 2023-12-26
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 203 to 2023-12-26
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 346 to 2023-12-27
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 381 to 2023-12-27
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 280 to 2023-12-28
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 205 to 2023-12-28
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 362 to 2023-12-29
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 272 to 2023-12-29
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 3 to 2023-12-30
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 337 to 2023-12-30
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 299 to 2023-12-31
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 385 to 2023-12-31
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 191 to 2024-01-01
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 354 to 2024-01-01
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 275 to 2024-01-02
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 226 to 2024-01-02
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 374 to 2024-01-03
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 198 to 2024-01-03
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 331 to 2024-01-04
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 220 to 2024-01-04
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 267 to 2024-01-05
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 271 to 2024-01-05
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 347 to 2024-01-06
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 307 to 2024-01-06
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 207 to 2024-01-07
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 16 to 2024-01-07
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 372 to 2024-01-08
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 199 to 2024-01-08
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 272 to 2024-01-09
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 331 to 2024-01-09
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 367 to 2024-01-10
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 207 to 2024-01-10
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 381 to 2024-01-11
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 230 to 2024-01-11
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 348 to 2024-01-12
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 356 to 2024-01-12
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 236 to 2024-01-13
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 344 to 2024-01-13
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 279 to 2024-01-14
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 278 to 2024-01-14
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 307 to 2024-01-15
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 367 to 2024-01-15
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 359 to 2024-01-16
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 222 to 2024-01-16
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 258 to 2024-01-17
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 221 to 2024-01-17
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 237 to 2024-01-18
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 249 to 2024-01-18
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 344 to 2024-01-19
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 245 to 2024-01-19
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 337 to 2024-01-20
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 257 to 2024-01-20
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 271 to 2024-01-21
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 351 to 2024-01-21
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 297 to 2024-01-22
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 382 to 2024-01-22
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 16 to 2024-01-23
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 372 to 2024-01-23
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 194 to 2024-01-24
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 217 to 2024-01-24
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 325 to 2024-01-25
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 317 to 2024-01-25
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 202 to 2024-01-26
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 197 to 2024-01-26
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 351 to 2024-01-27
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 194 to 2024-01-27
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 310 to 2024-01-28
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 357 to 2024-01-28
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 309 to 2024-01-29
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 204 to 2024-01-29
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 370 to 2024-01-30
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 288 to 2024-01-30
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 205 to 2024-01-31
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 290 to 2024-01-31
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 387 to 2024-02-01
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 210 to 2024-02-01
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 254 to 2024-02-02
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 285 to 2024-02-02
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 199 to 2024-02-03
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 375 to 2024-02-03
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 210 to 2024-02-04
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 3 to 2024-02-04
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 340 to 2024-02-05
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 383 to 2024-02-05
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 221 to 2024-02-06
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 368 to 2024-02-06
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 213 to 2024-02-07
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 370 to 2024-02-07
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 345 to 2024-02-08
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 258 to 2024-02-08
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 269 to 2024-02-09
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 384 to 2024-02-09
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 382 to 2024-02-10
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 362 to 2024-02-10
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 253 to 2024-02-11
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 387 to 2024-02-11
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 246 to 2024-02-12
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 267 to 2024-02-12
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 284 to 2024-02-13
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 309 to 2024-02-13
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 245 to 2024-02-14
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 299 to 2024-02-14
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 365 to 2024-02-15
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 364 to 2024-02-15
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 357 to 2024-02-16
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 322 to 2024-02-16
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 265 to 2024-02-17
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 253 to 2024-02-17
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 281 to 2024-02-18
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 324 to 2024-02-18
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 200 to 2024-02-19
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 35 to 2024-02-19
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 226 to 2024-02-20
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 191 to 2024-02-20
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 317 to 2024-02-21
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 310 to 2024-02-21
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 212 to 2024-02-22
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 202 to 2024-02-22
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 304 to 2024-02-23
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 293 to 2024-02-23
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 278 to 2024-02-24
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 280 to 2024-02-24
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 368 to 2024-02-25
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 266 to 2024-02-25
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 215 to 2024-02-26
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 377 to 2024-02-26
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 294 to 2024-02-27
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 311 to 2024-02-27
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 252 to 2024-02-28
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 297 to 2024-02-28
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 251 to 2024-02-29
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 269 to 2024-02-29
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 243 to 2024-03-01
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 352 to 2024-03-01
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 220 to 2024-03-02
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 343 to 2024-03-02
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 364 to 2024-03-03
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 305 to 2024-03-03
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 203 to 2024-03-04
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 248 to 2024-03-04
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 292 to 2024-03-05
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 284 to 2024-03-05
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 356 to 2024-03-06
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 325 to 2024-03-06
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 35 to 2024-03-07
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 318 to 2024-03-07
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 377 to 2024-03-08
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 304 to 2024-03-08
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 373 to 2024-03-09
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 345 to 2024-03-09
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 222 to 2024-03-10
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 213 to 2024-03-10
OnboardingVM    D  Items without date after: 0
DailyItemVM     D  Repo. Updated date of item: 263 to 2024-03-11
OnboardingVM    D  Items without date after: 0
```

Comment: A suspend function will _suspend_ the coroutine until it completes. In other words, the calls to `fetchRemoteData()` and `assignDates()` are sequential with respect to each other. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Please provide implementation of related functions. What you did is actually correct - to execute suspend functions in order, we simply invoke them one after another.

Comment: "My current implementation results in the second function being run twice" -- what is "the second function"?

Comment: The second function is `assignDates()`. I've added more code in my question above.

Comment: Apparently, you create `OnboardingViewModel` twice - all logs are doubled, including "Show onboarding: true". You need to verify where/why it is instantiated.

Comment: Oh... I get it now. It's called by the OnboardingScreen and also in MainActiviy, because I needed access to the `showOnboarding` property. Very stupid of me. Thank you, broot!!!